# Уважаемые эксперты, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с запятыми: не понимаю, нужно ли обособлять слова (может / а может)

Tags: пунктуация

Возможно, в отрицательном ключе, может(,) перечисляет преимущества, а может(,) сравнивает два понятия.

Comment: Если бы вы еще помогли нам со смыслом фразы разобраться... Набор слов какой-то.

Comment: _Vladimir: Уважаемые эксперты, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с запятыми..."_ === Вместо второй запятой (после "ключе") нужен какой-то другой знак: точка, тире... Тогда, может быть, фраза будет иметь смысл.

Comment: @slava1947: а я так понял, что это три варианта чего-то (включая и первый при "возможно").

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *а я так понял, что это три варианта чего-то* Для этого не хватает: 1) глагола в первой части, 2) какого-то объединения (хотя бы контекстного)  "отрицательного ключа" с одной стороны  и "преимуществ" с "перечислениями" - с другой. Без этого при такой пунктуации выглядит дико: "Возможно, вечерним дилижансом, может, в огороде бузина, а может, в Киеве дядька". .

Comment: @behemothus: хахаха))) Да, согласен с вами. Но это уже к автору.

Answer (score 1):

"Может" здесь вводное слово, потому что от него нельзя задать вопроса к другим словам. Поэтому обе запятые нужны. Во втором случае вводное слово "может" сливается с союзом "а", и запятая между ними не ставится.

Comment: Аи как вы фразу-то поняли?

Comment: @behemothus: видимо, речь о том, что это характеристика какого-то действия человека, о котором должно было быть сказано раньше. Хотя тоже вопрос, может ли то, что мы видим, быть отдельной фразой или только продолжением другой.

Comment: Да я не об этом. Синтаксис как вы поняли?  "возможно", "может", "а может" - это что, однородные члены? Или как? "Возможно, (что) в отрицательном ключе (нечто) может то-то, а может и это"?

Comment: Да, я воспринял их как однородные члены, а не так, что "нечто может то-то". Так "может" было бы членом предложения, я же воспринимаю их все вводными словами.

Comment: Я вам в в комментах к вопросу по сути и ответил.